# Snowflake: Transpose table without aggregation

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with 2 columns: numerical value and label:

| value | label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |
| 4 | A |
| 5 | B |

And the desired output after transpose is:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | null |

There are a few challenges:

1. Tried pivot but it has to be with an aggregation, which is not desired in this case since i need to keep all values for label A and B, no min/max/avg etc.
2. label A and B is not constant, they are variables chosen from a dropdown, and it may go all the way from A-Z(so number of columns are not fixed either), therefore not able to use case/when.
3. As shown in the table, each label may have a different number of values, need fill null at the end.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!